# How bad is this proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions

I am proving that 
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \left \lvert \mathbb{E}[e^{itX}] \right \rvert = 0$$
in the case in whic $X$ has a density function $f(x)$ (wrt the Lebesgue measure).

It seems to good to be true to proceed as follows...

$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{itx} \mathrm{d} x
=
\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} f\left(\frac{y}{t}\right) e^{iy} \mathrm{d} x
$$
thanks to the change of variable $y=tx$.
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} f\left(\frac{y}{t}\right) e^{iy} \mathrm{d} x
=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} f\left(\frac{y}{t}\right) e^{iy} \mathrm{d} x
$$
By dominated convergence ($f$ on any compact around 0 has a maximum).

And $ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} f\left(\frac{y}{t}\right)$ goes to 0 as $t \to \infty$.

I guess that is it wrong since I am assuming continuity of $f$, right?

Comment: Exactly how did you apply the DCT???

Comment: DCT does not apply. This result is immediate from  Riemann  Lebesgue Lemma See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, sorry, I meant that in the title, i wrongly wrote 'integral' in place of Lemma.

Comment: @copper.hat, if we assume continuity of $f$ at 0, it means that for $t$ big enough $f(y/t)$ will be close to $f(0)$ hence dominated. I was wondering if that could fail in the case of $f$ not continuous. In case do you have counterexamples?

Comment: That argument is a little too vague for me, I am afraid. You need to explicitly show a dominating function.